# função Hover JQuery em elementos dinâmicos

Tags: jquery, css-hover

Existe alguma forma de usar o evento de `hover` com jQuery em options de selects criados dinamicamente. Tentei usar a função `on()` e o `live()` mas não deu certo.

Tentei assim:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.teste', function () {
    alert("teste");
});

$(document).live('hover', '.teste', function () {
    alert("teste");
});

$(document).delegate('hover', '.teste', function () {
    alert("teste");
});

$('.teste').hover(function () {
    alert("teste");
});
```

tentei também com `mouseover()` no lugar de `hover()`

Comment: tente o seguinte $("contexto").delegate("#id", "acao", function(e){ ... })

Exemplo: $(" body ").delegate("#uf", "hover", function(e){ .. })

Comment: Acrescente um exemplo do que você ja tentou fazer

Comment: Dependendo da versão do jQuery esse `delegate` e o `live` foram substituído pelo `on`.

Comment: Tenta com mouseenter

Comment: @Zoom verdade, bem observado!

Comment: @JoabNunes no .delegate() você inverteu a ordem... primeiro é o elemento e depois a ação: $("body").delegate(".uf", "hover", function(){})

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro termo é o evento, o segundo é o elemento. Mas não basta por somente a classe, tem que por o elemento também, concatenado com a classe ou não. Se é um `a`, se é uma `div`, enfim.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', 'div.elemento', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }).on('mouseout', 'div.elemento', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elemento">
  Teste
</div>
```

Comment: Com o `option` do `select` não funciona.

Comment: realmente, com o option não funciona

Comment: Não funciona mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O `option`, não aceita tal personalização, a solução seria criar um select do zero, acompanhado [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284510/detect-mouseover-of-select-option-in-all-browsers) no *Stack Overflow* consegui implementar algo parecido e que atinja seu objetivo:

```js
contador = 0; // verifica se lista esta ou nao aberta

// hover na opção
$("#optionlist label").on('mouseenter', function(){
  /* muda minha div result para o texto do meu 
     label com hover*/
    $(".result").text($(this).text());  
});

// clique no input select
$("#select").on('click', function(e){
  
    e.stopPropagation(); //cancela propagração de clique
  
  if(contador == 0)
  { // se a lista tiver fechada
    $("#optionlist").show();  // abre minha lista de opções
    contador = 1;
  }
  else
  { // se a lista tiver aberta
     $("#optionlist").hide();  // fecha minha lista de opções
     contador = 0;
  }
    
});

//quando ele seleconar uma opção
$("#optionlist label").on('click', function(){ 
  
    var text = $(this).attr("id"); // pega id do radio selecionado
    $("#select").val(text); //muda o texto do select
    $("#optionlist").hide(); // fecha lista de opções
    contador = 1;
});
```

```css
body{padding-top: 50px;}
label {
    display:block;
    height:21px;
    width: 100%;
}

label:hover{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}

#optionlist{
   display: none;
   position: relative;
   left: -1px;
   width: 117px;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid #B5B0AC;
   overflow-y: auto;
   height:60px;
}

.result{float:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="result"></div>

<input name="cor" id="select" type="text" readonly value="red"/>

<fieldset id="optionlist">
  <label id="red"> red </label>
  <label id="blue"> blue </label>
  <label id="green"> green </label>   
  <label id="orange"> orange </label>       
</fieldset>
```

Para usar o valor escolhido, basta pegar o valor do `input` com nome `cor`.

Comment: Achei legal **montar o select** assim. Eu montaria com marcadores.

Comment: Esse foi apenas cópia e cola da outra pergunta, estou organizando (limpando) aos poucos